# Chernoff bound with an upper bound on the expectation

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose that $X$ is a sum of i.i.d Bernoulli random variables and $[]=\mu$, according to the Multiplicative Chernoff bound we have that

$Pr( \leq (1-\delta)\mu) \leq \exp (\frac{-\delta^2}{2}\mu)$, for all $0<\delta<1.$

My question: if we are given an upper bound on the expectation instead of a lower bound i.e. $\mu=E[X]\leq \mu'$, is it still true that there exists a constant  such that

$Pr( \leq (1-\delta)\mu) \leq \exp (-c \delta^2 \mu')$ ?

Since it is easy to see if we are given a lower bound on the expectation i.e. $\mu' \leq E[X]=\mu$, then $Pr( \leq (1-\delta)\mu) \leq \exp (\frac{-\delta^2}{2}\mu)\leq \exp (\frac{-\delta^2}{2}\mu')$, but if we just know an upper bound on $E[X]$ I tried to see it e.g. using stronger versions of Chernoff but couldn't ... and  I want to check if it is true in the first case as I am not having any intuition ...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $X$ is a _sum_ of iid Bernoulli random variables, then $E[X] = \mu$ has value $np$ where $p$ is the common parameter of the Bernoulli random variables. Usually $\mu > 1$ and so your "for all $0 < \mu < 1$" is very suspicious.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I just edited. It is supposed to be for all small $\delta$. Hope now it is clear.